# Is ElementRef required to get dragstart DragEvent in Angular 2?

Tags: angular

In this gist https://gist.github.com/gatimus/5abe1fb2ef45f26657ed6843902b872b I am listening for dragstart event on 2 elements. One with angular 2 syntax and one with native element reference. Only adding the event listener with the native element reference was I able to get a DragEvent with dataTransfer property. `ElementRef` is considered a security risk and seemingly you should be able to accomplish the same with the Angular 2 event binding syntax. Is `ElementRef` required to get dragstart DragEvent in Angular 2 and is this a Angular 2 bug?

```
import { Component, OnInit, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    template: `
        <!-- native element reference -->
        <div id="source0"
             style="background-color: red; height: 20px;"
             draggable="true">
        </div>

        <!-- angular 2 template syntax -->
        <div id="source1"
             style="background-color: green; height: 20px;"
             draggable="true"
             (dragstart)="dragStart($event)">
        </div>
    `
})
export class DragAndDropComponent implements OnInit {

    public source0: HTMLElement;

    constructor(private _elementRef: ElementRef) { }

    // native element reference
    ngOnInit() {
        this.source0 = (<HTMLElement>(<HTMLElement>this._elementRef.nativeElement).children[0]);
        this.source0.addEventListener('dragstart', (event) => {
            console.log('source0', event); // DragEvent with dataTransfer property 
            event.dataTransfer.effectAllowed = 'move'; // No error
            event.dataTransfer.setData('text/plain', 'test'); // No error
        });
    }

    // angular 2 template syntax
    dragStart(event: DragEvent) {
        console.log('source1', event); // Object with MouseEvent for srcEvent
        event.dataTransfer.effectAllowed = 'move'; // Cannot set property 'effectAllowed' of undefined
        event.dataTransfer.setData('text/plain', 'test'); //Cannot read property 'setData' of undefined
    }

}
```

Edit: 
It turns out this is only duplicatable when `MaterialModule` is imported and the required HammerJS is loaded. Is there a way to have HammerJS not override the event handling through angular 2? I am only including HammerJS to load material 2 without error.

Comment: Questions should contain the relevant parts directly instead of linking to external resources.

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem https://plnkr.co/edit/mYRUDHfkTmYYD4vRhcUo?p=preview

Comment: Thank you @Günter Zöchbauer, this lets me know I need to find out why my project has different behavior on the same component then on plunker.

Comment: It is duplicatable when you add the `MaterialModule` and required HammerJS https://plnkr.co/edit/BHcLTU?p=preview

Comment: I don't know hammer but I assume it's the cause. It needs to be configured but I don't know details.

Answer (score 1):

To get the normal event behavior after  including material 2 and hammerjs you provide an basic HammerGestureConfig to the current module.

```
@Injectable()
export class AppGestureConfig extends HammerGestureConfig { }

@NgModule({
  imports: [ BrowserModule, MaterialModule.forRoot() ],
  providers: [{ provide: HAMMER_GESTURE_CONFIG, useClass: AppGestureConfig }],
  declarations: [ App ],
  bootstrap: [ App ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/Qeip4T?p=preview

Edit:
Here is the issue on github
https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/1457